# Using plugin_dir_path() with WordPress on MAMP

Tags: plugins, include

I have the following directory structure:

Root Install: /Users/philipdowner/Sites/montanaliving

Within the root installation I have the following plugin structure:

/wp-content/plugins/manifest-rets/

Then, within the plugin folder I have 2 php files
manifest-rets.php
phrets.php

In the main plugin file, I have the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Manifest RETS
Plugin URI: http://manifestbozeman.com
Description: Uses the phRETS library to connect to a RETS server
Version: 1.0b
Author: Philip Downer
Author URI:http://philipdowner.com
License: GPL2
*/

define('MR_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));    

//echo MR_PLUGIN_PATH;
include_once(MR_PLUGIN_PATH.'phprets.php'); 

?>
```

However, when running the plugin I get the following error stating that the phrets.php file could not be found. It's driving me batty! Any suggestions? Am I overlooking something obvious?

> Warning:
>   include_once(/Users/philipdowner/Sites/montanaliving/wp-content/plugins/manifest-rets/phprets.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /Users/philipdowner/Sites/montanaliving/wp-content/plugins/manifest-rets/manifest-rets.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/Users/philipdowner/Sites/montanaliving/wp-content/plugins/manifest-rets/phprets.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in
>   /Users/philipdowner/Sites/montanaliving/wp-content/plugins/manifest-rets/manifest-rets.php
>   on line 15

I've tried passing in the ABSPATH constant, and using PHP's set_include_path() function to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isn't working for you.

I usually set the plugin path constant using dirname(**FILE**)

You could try:

```
define('MR_PLUGIN_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));    

//echo MR_PLUGIN_PATH;
include_once(MR_PLUGIN_PATH.'/phprets.php');
```

Also:

Are you sure phprets.php exists. You say you have phrets.php (missing the p)

Comment: `plugin_dir_path` is just a wrapper around `dirname`.  It's body: `return trailingslashit(dirname($file));`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the way MAMP is setup. Do  you have any problems with any of the theme functions like `get_template_directory()`?

Try it this way and see what happens.

```
include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/phprets.php';
```